# AngularJS: apply filter for ngStyle

Tags: angularjs

Good day for everyone!

I have a problem with understanding AngularJS. Can I use my custom filter within ngStyle directive? Why it can't change opacity of span tag at the same time when I change value in input (but it change value in markup)? How I can realize this behaviour without direct using controller scope?

My raw code:
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="number" ng-model="slider" max="10" min="1">
        <span ng-style="{'opacity': '{{slider | filter}}'}">TEXT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.slider = 6;
        }])
        .filter('filter', function () {
            return function (input) {
                return 0.1 * input;
            };
        });
})();
```

My code at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkdkLac3/

Comment: Why use `ngStyle` instead of something like `ngClass` ?

Comment: because I can't make ten classes with 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0 values of opacity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering the general question, yes, generally you can use an user created `filter` in generic angular expressions. You might be having issues with `ng-attr` due to a parsing error (probably a bug in the angular parser). You can still use filters in `ng-attr` with

```
<span ng-style="{ 'opacity': (slider | opacity) }">TEXT</span>
```

`ng-attr` though is most beneficial for binding to style objects directly

```
<span ng-style="sliderStyle">TEXT</span>
```

you can also style directly by using

```
<span style="opacity: {{slider|opacity}}">TEXT</span>
```

with the below `filter`:

```
app.filter('opacity', function () {
    return function (input) {
       return 0.1 * input;
    };
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkdkLac3/8/)

Whichever solution is better mainly depends on where you plan to re-use things. Filters are available across all `scope`s, but this one in particular might only make sense for a given controller. Don't forget that reuse can be accomplished with directives (which can have a controller) as well.